# "Starting from version" vs "Starting with version" vs "Beginning with version"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, collocation

When you write about software it is quite common to read that a certain version has introduced a new feature. Usually the new feature also will be available in later releases. I found three different ways to say that:

> 1. *Starting from version* 2.0 you can upload bigger pictures
> 2. *Starting with version* 2.0 you can upload bigger pictures
> 3. *Beginning from version* 2.0 you can upload bigger pictures

Is there a right way to say it, or more than one way could be accepted?

A [google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Starting%20from%20version%2CStarting%20with%20version%2CBeginning%20with%20version%2C&year_start=1970&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t4%3B%2CStarting%20from%20version%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bstarting%20from%20version%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BStarting%20from%20version%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bstarting%20from%20Version%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BStarting%20from%20Version%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CStarting%20with%20version%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BStarting%20with%20version%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bstarting%20with%20version%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BStarting%20with%20Version%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bstarting%20with%20Version%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CBeginning%20with%20version%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BBeginning%20with%20version%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbeginning%20with%20version%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBeginning%20with%20Version%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbeginning%20with%20Version%3B%2Cc0) for the three shows that "Starting with version" is the most common, followed by "Beginning with version".

*A [similar questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112972/starting-with-vs-starting-from) has been asked in the past but I think this is a different use case*

Comment: I'd use *Beginning **with** version* only. *Starting from* leads me to think that I will travel an arc: "Starting with soup and salad...and make your way to dessert." It's really a matter of *since that version*.

Comment: Using ngrams does not prove what fits here any more than apple pie wants chocolate ice cream for ngrams saying the flavor is popular.

Comment: Related: [Starting with vs starting from](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112972/starting-with-vs-starting-from)

Comment: @YosefBaskin: Your analogy is a bit less than pellucid. Don